# Cannot install java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-windows-x64.exe on fresh Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows, sdk, java-7

When I try to execute the installer, it starts "Extracting Bundled Java SDK ..." and then fails with "Error: Could not find the required version of the Java(TM) 2 Runrime Environment in '(null)'.".

What can I do? The OS is a Windows 7 Ultimate (just installed), virtualized with KVM under an Ubuntu 13.10.

Firefox and LibreOffice could be installed without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The pre requisite for JavaEE sdk7 installer is to have Jdk 7. So make sure, your environment variable path is pointing to JDK7\bin folder. And check java -version in command prompt, it should show you jdk 7 is current version in your system.

If both of the above are correct and it still doesn't work, then  donot double click on the exe file directly, install it from command prompt, by giving location for JRE7 and 
helping the installer to find jar files of JRE7, see below:

D:\installables>java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-windows-x64.exe -j "C:\
Program Files\Java\jre7"

I had same problem, but this worked for me.